# Windows 10 AU Disk RAW

Tags: windows, windows-10

So there has been an issue with AU updates for Windows 10 since August. An update basically renders an SSD/HDD unreadable. It changes the disk to raw.

There was a reddit forum dedicated to this very issue:

https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/4vyifo/bug_windows_10_anniversary_update_tanked/?sort=old

...but has now been archived, so I cannot comment on it. I've looked to Microsoft, Transcend and Dell regarding this issue but no-one has anything to say.

Has anyone else had this issue, or currently still has it? Does anyone know of anyway to resolve it PERMANENTLY. Microsoft apparently were releasing an update to fix it, no updates released have fixed it.

I can take the machine back to the 1511 build, to fix the issue, but it will then want to upgrade to 1611, which again breaks the machine.

EDIT: I am aware of ways to temporarily fix the issue, I don't want that, I want a real resolution. It's been 7 months now.

Comment: If 1607 causes the problems you say it does, then waiting until 1703 is released, is the only solution.

Comment: Reading the most recent posts on the thread, it seems to me, the problem should have been fixed in the last month.  If you don't want to wait, upgrade your installation to the current CU Insider Preview build, then manually update using the release ISO to the final (stable) build to exist the Insider Preview branch.